# How to apply themes runtime?

Tags: asp.net

I want to build the application that contains themes with skins & css files.

That themes list should be seen to the user on web page. Whenever user select the theme in themes list that theme applied to the application throughout all pages.

Please rely me if you have any about to steps how to apply dynamic themes to the web application in master content pages.

I tried to apply themes on one single content page but the problem is I can not getting the value of dropdownlist selected item in the Page_Init event. It gives error object reference not set to an instance of object. how to catch the dropdownlist value in Page_Init method.

Also if I want to set the theme in web.config then how I can change that on runtime.

Please give reply..........

Regards
Girish

Comment: My email address is girishchaudhari.100@gmail.com & other is girish_v_chaudhari@yahoo.co.in

Answer (score 1):

There's a sample at [dotnettreats.com](http://www.dotnettreats.com) that does exactly what you need.  The only problem is the site was down when I wrote this.  I don't know when (or if) it's coming back online.

The project is called SampleThemes.  The sample includes a page with a DropDownList that lists by name the several Themes that are part of the project.  When the user selects an item, the page's Theme is set in the page's Theme property by the Theme's name on the page's Page_PreInit event.

Here' another link that discusses this (scroll down to 'Applying Themes Dynamically'):
http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Themes-In-ASP.NET.aspx

If you continue to have problems with this, post your email address in a comment and I'll email you the SampleThemes project.

Comment: Hi may email ID : girishchaudhari.100@gmail. Please end me sampleThemes projects.

Comment: I sent the project to both your email addresses.